# trying to derive expression with polynomial arithmetic

Tags: time-series, arima, unit-root

I'm trying to figure out how this is derived in "*Time Series Analysis - Forecasting and Control*" (Box, Jenkins): 
$$
a_t = \frac{1}{1-\theta B}z_t = (1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2+ ... +  + \theta^k B^k)(1-\theta^{k+1} B^{k+1})^{-1}z_t
$$

I can derive this :

$$\frac{1}{1-\theta B} = (1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2+ ... ) = (1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k) + \frac{\theta^{k+1}B^{k+1}}{1-\theta B} $$

How does one derive the top expression?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $1-\theta B$ to discover they are equal, *QED.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I got through it:

$\frac{1}{1 - \theta B} = (1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...) = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k) + (\theta^{k + 1}B^{k + 1} + \theta^{k + 2}B^{k + 2} + ...)$

$ = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k) + \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1}(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...)$

So now we have

$(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...) = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k) + \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1}(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...)$.

Subtracting gives

$(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...) - \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1}(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...) = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k)$

$\Rightarrow (1 - \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1})(1 + \theta B + \theta^2 B^2 + ...) = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k)$

And finally, dividing both sides by $(1 - \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1})$, gives the desired result:

$\frac{1}{1 - \theta B} = (1+ \theta B + \theta ^2B^2 + ... + \theta^kB^k)(1 - \theta^{k+1}b^{k+1})^{-1}$

Comment: OHhhh hahaha wow tricky. Thanks!